# git push error: repository not found even though remote url is added

Tags: git

I have added repository url using 
`git remote add origin https://github.com/**.git`
If I check with `git remote -v` I can able to see repo url , but still when pushing to same url,using `git push origin master` I found that
`remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/**.git/' not found`. Above repository url still alive and  I can able to clone but when pushing I stuck with this error What could may be the reason?

Comment: Could be a typo in the URL. Did you paste it into your browser and check?

Answer (score 2):

I have removed `.git` using `rm -rf .git` and again initilized the same using `git init`and i'm able to push the code.

Answer (score -1):

Follow these steps to avoid the issues.

Adding a project to GitHub without GitHub CLI.

Create a new repository on GitHub.com. To avoid errors, do not initialize the new repository with README, license, or ignore files. You can add these files after your project has been pushed to GitHub.

Create New Repository drop-down. Open Git Bash. Change the current working directory to your local project.

Initialize the local directory as a Git repository.

```
$ git init -b main
```

Add the files in your new local repository. This stages them for the first commit.

```
$ git add .
# Adds the files in the local repository and stages them for commit. To unstage a file, use 'git reset HEAD YOUR-FILE'.
```

Commit the files that you've staged in your local repository.

```
$ git commit -m "First commit"
# Commits the tracked changes and prepares them to be pushed to a remote repository. To remove this commit and modify the file, use 'git reset --soft HEAD~1' and commit and add the file again.
```

At the top of your repository on GitHub.com's Quick Setup page, click  to copy the remote repository URL.
Copy remote repository URL field
In the Command prompt, add the URL for the remote repository where your local repository will be pushed.

```
$ git remote add origin  <REMOTE_URL> 
# Sets the new remote
$ git remote -v
# Verifies the new remote URL
Push the changes in your local repository to GitHub.com.
$ git push origin main
# Pushes the changes in your local repository up to the remote repository you specified as the origin
```